# Is Node.js applicable here?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've got a plan for four systems: A, B, C and D.

System A is to hold a small database which will accept information from the other three systems via HTTP requests--I'll try to implement a RESTful service here. The other systems only talk to System A.

System B and C both produce a .csv file which I need to monitor for changes and then send their contents back to system A with a timestamp. I'm afraid that while communicating back to A, a file change might be made but the system will ignore it because it's busy.

System D will be run by the client on a browser.

Is Node.js appropriate to run on systems B and C? To monitor the file changes and send some PUT/POST requests to System A? In the rare case of an update taking very long to occur on System A, will Node.js be able to send another request if it sees a file change while the first one is trying to finish? I've never used Node, but I feel like this is what it's good for. I'm willing to give it a shot.

Comment: Yes; Node.js is perfectly capable of sending multiple async requests in parallel.

Comment: You can use any programming language (either compiled to native code or with a runtime like Node.js) that you like for systems A, B and C. The appropriateness depends on a lot of different factors.

Comment: I don't buy that this is "opinion-based". Is it really just opinion whether or not node will fit in this distributed architecture? He described the high-level job pretty well and I think it's safe to say that node fits his use-case just fine. He didn't ask anyone to suggest other tools for the job, he asked if one specific tool could do the job, and the answer is yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm afraid that while communicating back to A, a file change might be made but the system will ignore it because it's busy.

Well worry not because node is built from its very core to be asynchronous. [It's very tagline is](https://nodejs.org/):

> Node.js® is a platform built on Chrome's JavaScript runtime for easily building fast, scalable network applications. **Node.js uses an event-driven, non-blocking I/O model that makes it lightweight and efficient, perfect for data-intensive real-time applications that run across distributed devices.**

You could certainly use other languages/platforms to solve your use-case as well, but node was practically designed for stuff like this :)

I play a game called Hearthstone and the game generates a log file of what happens as the game progresses. I wrote a little [log watcher module](https://github.com/hearthpal/hearthstone-log-watcher) that monitors the Hearthstone log file. [This code snippet](https://github.com/hearthpal/hearthstone-log-watcher/blob/master/index.js#L59-L76) is the portion that monitors the file.

So far my app has never missed any lines in the log file since each of the file change events are queued up as changes happen. My app doesn't block while waiting for file changes and then processing them. Instead, node adds events to the queue and checks their status with each iteration of the event loop. Eventually it processes *all* the file change events no matter what.